# Images are not loadig in my home page silder Wordpress Site

Tags: jquery, wordpress, nivo-slider

I am not sure about the absolute JS error my images are not coming in the slider.

My Site is :-  URL

Instead of JS error

`$ is not a function at` --

```
   $(function() {
   $('#design_thumbs a').lightBox();
   });
```

Its working correctly before with the JS error. The only thing i did is changed my home page.

Let me know how can i make this working tried `jQuery.noConflict();`

But no help :(  (above code is in my `header.php`  ).

Comment: which one nivo slider or there is other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution on my own.

This theme i am using on my site [THEME FOREST THEME](http://themeforest.net/item/pekaboo-for-wordpress-children-theme-template/409980) , and no JS errors were reflecting so there is no JS issue.

However i have to made some changes in the `common-functions.php` file of my theme which have a setting for the home page only.

Code is ->

```
if (is_page_template('page-home.php') ) {
```

**COMMENT** the Line and change it to something like this ->

```
//if (is_page_template('page-home.php') ) {
if ( is_page(67) ) {   //change 67 with your page id
```

Also in the `header.php` modify the CSS for nivo slider css effects-

Change this code to something like this for your page

```
<?php if ( is_page_template('page-home.php')) { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/nivo-slider.css"/>
<?php }; ?>
```

Change to (with the page id code)

```
<?php if ( is_page(67)) { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/nivo-slider.css"/>
<?php }; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this way:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#design_thumbs a').lightBox();
});
```

there are several more ways:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  jQuery('#design_thumbs a').lightBox();
});
```

and this one too:

```
(function($) {
  jQuery('#design_thumbs a').lightBox();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: try one of these one by one may be this helps.

Comment: even i tried with this too -- var $swap = jQuery.noConflict(); and swap(function() {
  swap('#design_thumbs a').lightBox();
});

Comment: i see that your div of nivoslider has the id'slider' and you are not referencing to the nivoslider.

Comment: what should i do for this..heavily stuck at it ..totally out of mind on this :(

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that maybe the jquery library in the `<head>` might not be loading until after that `<script>` in the `<body>` executes. I'm a little fuzzy with the order in which scripts load, but I know that they do load asynchronously in series when placed in the `<head>`. As for the `<body>`, I believe they execute synchronously as the content loads in the page. Try moving the script into the head, because `$(function(){})` is just a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){})`.

Comment: I tried by moving the script block from my head to footer even ..but no magic :( .. although im not sure but i think it might be some settings under php file as its a Peekaboo wordpress theme and codecanyon may have done something to tight bound the functionality of this ..just a thought let me know your opinion

Comment: No, what I was suggesting was to move the 

    `$(function() {
      $('#design_thumbs a').lightBox();
    });`

To the `<head>` below all the other scripts.